# Django - ConnectionAbortedError: [WinError 10053] An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine

Tags: django, connection

i have a really trange problem, when i run my django server, even the simplest one it calls this error once every like 1 minute. ConnectionAbortedError: [WinError 10053] An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine. The thing is, nothing is breaking. Server is running fine. I've tried to trun off firewall but it didnt help and also when i turned off my antivirus program, it still makes this error. I have newest version of python and django installed. Does anybody know how to fix this? I've searched for over one day for this problem solution, but i didnt find anything helpful.
[image: error on output]